# DtSQL GUI not opening in Ubuntu 16.04 (UnsatisfiedLinkError)

Tags: 16.04, java

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/webmind25/Downloads/dtsql_linux_5_2_1/jre/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so: libXtst.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.jsoft.dtsql.MainRunner.main(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 6):

UnsatisfiedLinkError generally means a missing library. Try installing the package that provides the library mentioned by the error:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libxtst6
```

If that does not work, then try installing the 32 bit version of the package:

```
sudo apt install libxtst6:i386
```

(it's possible you may have to do `dpkg --add-architecture i368` first)

---

Found this particular case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355863/cant-find-install-libxtst-so-6) on Stack Overflow